# How can i use async move closure in a unasync call back?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

this's a click call back function for a fltk button,I want to execute a database query on the click of a button.

```
    //button click even
    ui.but.set_callback(async move |_| {
        let txt = "Some long text!Some long text!Some long text!Some long text!Some long text!\n";
        log.buffer().unwrap().append(txt);
        my_db::sqlserver_mod2::sql2().await.unwrap();
    });
```

I got an error:

```
[E0308] mismatched types. 
[Note] expected `()`, found opaque type
```

How can i use  async move closure in a unasync call back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `set_callback()` is:

```
fn set_callback<F: FnMut(&mut Self) + 'static>(&mut self, cb: F)
```

In other words, the callback must not return anything. But your callback

```
async move |_| {
  //skipped      
});
```

has a return type of:

```
impl Future<Output=()>
```

which is an anonymous future that returns nothing. So you cannot use an async closure as your callback.

Instead, you should pass a closure of the expected type and do your processing inside it:

```
ui.but.set_callback(move |_| {
        let txt = "Some long text!Some long text!Some long text!Some long text!Some long text!\n";
        log.buffer().unwrap().append(txt);

         //acquire a runtime somehow, see the docs of your preferred runtime
        runtime.spawn(async {
            my_db::sqlserver_mod2::sql2().await.unwrap();
        });

    });
```

And last , but not least - you should avoid doing slow operations inside the UI, as it will appear unresponsive. Consider offloading the the work to another thread. For instance you can start tokio and pre-spawn your handlers which should work in a producer-consumer model and just pass commands via channels from the UI (the producer).